# How to perform join on MySQL (JDBC) with Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to read data from MySQL through Spark.
The API which I saw is able to read data from specific table.
something like,

```
val prop = new java.util.Properties
prop.setProperty("user", "<username>")
prop.setProperty("password", "<password>")

sparkSession.read.jdbc("jdbc:mysql://????:3306/???", "some-table", prop)
```

Now, I would like to perform a query for join tables. Does anyone know how to do it (on the database side, not with Spark SQL) ?

Thanks,

Eran

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to use the "table " argument as a query:

```
val table = "(SELECT foo JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.id) as t"

spark.read.jdbc("jdbc:mysql://????:3306/???", table, prop)
```

You should note that giving an alias to your query is important or this won't work.

Comment: you didn't need to make this as wiki

Comment: @eliasah So many edits...  and I make all my posts wikis :) Thanks for the additions!

Comment: You'll need some rep if you want to continue giving bounties :P

Comment: You can use `query` attribute as well, and you will not need to use the alias