# How to fastly execute mysql query in spark scala

Tags: mysql, eclipse, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use Scala spark within eclipse to obtain data from MySQL database.
The problem is that the code is taking hours juste to execute one SQL query.
This is my initial code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val sqlcontext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
sqlcontext.setConf("url", "mysql://localhost:3306/myDB?user=us&password=pw")

val action = sqlcontext.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "action").registerTempTable("action")
val session = sqlcontext.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "session").registerTempTable("session")
sqlcontext.cacheTable("action")
sqlcontext.cacheTable("session")
```

Then in order to obtain data from the database I tried many commands

```
val data = sqlcontext.sql('SELECT * FROM action INNER JOIN session ON action.session_id = session.session_id")
```

This takes many hours to be done, so I tried juste to get the table:

```
val df = sqlcontext.table("action").collect()
println(df.size)
```

But this did not solve my problem. Finally just want to say that my action table contains about 11 millions rows.

Any Idea?

Comment: Add indexes on action.session_id and session.session_id and let us know if performance improves.

Comment: What is the exact query that you are trying to perform ?

Comment: You should include the schemas for both your `action` and `session` tables in your question. Knowing their data structure and existing indexes will help others identify areas for optimisation.

Comment: The fast way is to skip Spark join. You can execute join in MySQL directly and fetch the results:

- http://stackoverflow.com/q/40720619/6022341

Comment: My tables are indexed, I do not think that it is about the join because I have the same problem when trying to retrieve a table without join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are multiple reasons for long running job. As you mentioned your master is "local" you are running on a single executor thread. Spark will do better when it is partitioned well. please check how many partitions are created in your case. if it is one please do  re-partition by using  repartition(numberofpartitions : int) and run with more threads to achieve parallel processing(local[8]/local[*]).

Comment: You are right, I know that Spark is much slower in local, but I suppose that will not take hours to juste load a table. I replaced sqlcontext.table line by:

    val v = sqlcontext.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "session", "date_created", chanStartDate, System.currentTimeMillis(), 200)

where 200 is the number of partitions, and now it takes some minutes to get the table in local which is good for a local version, I think that it will be better too on the server.

Thank you.